# Is $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}$ a simple field extension?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

By simple extension I mean that the exists an element $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and thus $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{Q}=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$. By considering $\alpha$ to be $i$ do we have what we are looking for?

To finish complete the exercise can anyone please confirm that this field extension is in fact algebraic but not finite?

Thank you

Comment: It is of course not algebraic, hence indeed not finite, and therefore not equal to $\Bbb Q(i)/\Bbb Q$.

Comment: It is not simple, since $\Bbb C$ is uncountable.

Comment: But with $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$, we have that $\mathbb{C}$ is uncountable, yet $\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}(i)/\mathbb{R}$. And so, we conclude that the cardinality of the bigger field does not affect the property for a field to be simple, right?

Comment: @HornyPigeon54 Indeed, the cardinality of the bigger field alone is not really a relevant property. $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$ have the _same_ (infinite) cardinality. That's not true for $\Bbb Q$ and $\Bbb C$.

Comment: $$|\Bbb C|>|\Bbb Q|=|\Bbb Q(\alpha)|.$$

Answer (score 2):

It is **not** algebraic, since there are non-algebraic ie. *transcendental* numbers in $\Bbb R \subseteq \Bbb C$. The numbers $\pi$ and $e$ come to mind. As far as I know this is not that easy to show. In the case of $\pi$ it is a theorem of Lindemann. @AnneBauval's cardinality argument is quite nice to show that there exist *some* transcendental elements in $\Bbb R \mid \Bbb Q$. Anyway, using this it is clear that $\Bbb C$ cannot be a simple algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$, let alone $\Bbb Q(i)$, since the latter **is** a simple algebraic extension of $\Bbb Q$.

Now let me hijack the question: It could still be the case that $\Bbb C$ is simple in the sense that $\Bbb C \cong \Bbb Q(x)$ for some *transcendental* element $x$, ie. that $\Bbb C$ is a field of rational functions in one variable over $\Bbb Q$. But again we can use @AnneBauval's trick to deduce that $\Bbb Q(x) \cong \operatorname{Frac}(\Bbb Q[x])$ is a countable field, so out of cardinality reasons $\Bbb C$ cannot even be a simple transcendental extension of $\Bbb Q$.